# How can I get a constructor for a type when one of the parameters is dynamic?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, constructor

I have a series of classes with this constructor:

```
MyClass(Reader reader, dynamic json)  { ... }
```

I need to instantiate objects in a generic method.  To do so I tried to get the constructor thuswise:

```
class Reader
...
T  Get<T>(string id)
    {
    dynamic  json        = GetData(id);
    var      constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Reader), typeof(dynamic) });
    return constructor.Invoke(new object[] { this, json });
    }
```

However, neither `dynamic` nor `typeof(dynamic)` is acceptable in this circumstance.  What's the appropriate way to do so?  The constructor certainly does exist.  There does not seem to be a binding flag for this situation.

For the moment, I've created a dead-simple `JsonWrapper` class as a workaround:

```
class JsonWrapper
{
JsonWrapper(dynamic json) { Json = json; }
dynamic  Json  { get;  private set; }
}
...
var  constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Reader), typeof(JsonWrapper) });
```

I could also call `GetConstructors()` and take the first entry, as these classes only have the one - but that would be fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, neither `dynamic` nor `typeof(dynamic)` is acceptable in this circumstance.

Consider using `typeof(object)` instead of `typeof(dynamic)`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) says about `dynamic` that

> In most cases, it functions like it has type object.

In particular, the following code fails with error *"Type '....JsonWrapper' already defines a member called 'JsonWrapper' with the same parameter types"*

```
public class JsonWrapper
{
    public JsonWrapper(dynamic json) { }
    public JsonWrapper(object json) { }
}
```

Comment: No joy; calling `GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Reader), typeof(object) })' returns `null`.  I did remember to change my constructor sig back to `Reader, dynamic`.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Do you mean that if you have a constructor `JsonWrapper(object)` then you can retrieve  it with `GetConstructor`, but if you change the signature to `JsonWrapper(dynamic)` it does not work any more?

Comment: My workaround is to make the constructor accept `Reader, JsonWrapper` as parameters; if so, I can call `GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Reader), typeof(JsonWrapper) })`.  This is a bit of a kludge, so (following your suggestion) I tried changing the constructor back to `Reader, dynamic`, where I started, and using `GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(Reader),  typeof(object)})`.  However, this returned null, meaning no matching constructors found.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I tried, it seems to work for me if MyClass ctor is public and fails if it is private. Could it be your case? You can use another overload of `GetConstructor` to retrieve a private one.

Comment: Interesting.  The constructors have been `internal` all along.  So a `public Ctor(dynamic)` or `internal Ctor(SomeClass)` constructor will be returned, but `internal Ctor(dynamic)` doesn't.  Bizarre.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I could not reproduce it. For me getting `internal` ctors always fail. (Unless I use another overload of `GetConstructor`, `GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance ...)`.)